# Next js 14 layout component dynamic

Tags: next.js

I have a layout component with client component .
It's just a side menu where I need to render different link's base of user role. (it's a client component)
Question is how I should pass the user role there?
In each page (which goes as children thru this layout) I already making an api call to get a user role data.
Making one more api call inside ProfileSideMenu doesn't sound right to me.
Not sure if making this api call inside layout itself is also good idea.

On the other hand, Next JS docs says that it's okay to make several same api call's since the data is cached.

What is a solution here?

```
const ProfileLayout = async ({ children }: { children: ReactElement }) => {
  return (
    <div className='grid grid-cols-1 p-4'>
      <div className='grid grid-cols-8'>
        <div className='hidden md:block col-span-1'>
          <div className='grid grid-cols-4  h-full'>
            <ProfileSideMenu />
            <Divider orientation='vertical' className='col-start-5 h-full' />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='grid col-span-8 md:col-span-7 p-5'>{children}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few ways to solve this problem.

1. Create a context
   read this https://vercel.com/guides/react-context-state-management-nextjs
2. Make the API call in the layout and pass the role to the child pages and components

there are probably some other ways that i cant think of at the moment

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to handle user role is using React `Context` hook. You can create a `userContext` hook that holds the user role. You would fetch the user role in a higher level component (may be your root `page.tsx` or custom `AuthProvider` component). and then user `UserContext.Provider` to make role available to any component in the tree.

I will show a higher level explanation.

`userContext.tsx` :-

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, ReactNode } from 'react';

const UserContext = createContext(null);

export function UserProvider({ children, userRole }) {
  return <UserContext.Provider value={userRole}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>;
}

export function useUserRole() {
  const context = useContext(UserContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error('useUserRole must be used within a UserProvider');
  }
  return context;
}
```

Then wrap your higher order component using `useProvider` wrapper. You would need to ensure that the user role is fetched and passed to the `UserProvider` at this level (Where you have access to all page props).

```
// root `page.tsx` or a similar high-level component
import { UserProvider } from './UserContext';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, userRole }) {
  return (
    <UserProvider userRole={userRole}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </UserProvider>
  );
}
```

then use `useUserRole` to determine which links to render.

`ProfileSideMenu.tsx` :-

```
import { useUserRole } from './UserContext';

const ProfileSideMenu = () => {
  const userRole = useUserRole();

  // Use userRole to determine which links to render
};
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I do have a AuthContext which wraps whole app. The problem is I don't have a userRole there. That's user context is from Firebase Auth basically, but role set in our own server. When we create a user I can update Firebase Auth with new claim userRole, and it will  solve the problem. 
But then In case useRole changed, I have to update  it  in both places, in my db and Firebase. 
But yeah, seems like I have to pass it somewhere from higher level.